# Laravel dynamic config variable get

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-5, config

This is my `config/filesystems.php` file.

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 's3'),

'disks' => [
       's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        ],
       'b2' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('B2_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('B2_APP_KEY'),
        ],
]
```

How can I get `default` `filesystem`'s `key` value?
I think this is possible.

`config("filesystems.disks." . config("filesystems.default") . ".key")`;

I believe there is any better way.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's how I would do it. I don't know of a better or built-in way.

Comment: You can create a common helper function and set values according to your requirement.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change config value you should call `config` helper function and pass the value you want to set as the second argument. You can check it in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-config)